# Loops, what and how to use? (for, while, and foreach)

Tags: php, loops, laravel-5

What's up guys!

I have a problem and I can not think of a solution.

I need to make a report using DOMPDF. 
In this report, i need to print some employee information. In each page it is necessary to have header for the signature of the person in charge.

I have a group of employees. They are divided by departments.

I need a "break the page" loop when I change the employee's department or when I print 15 employees. After that, the loop should print the rest of the employees and execute the same rules if you change the employee's department again or have already been printed 15 employees.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Relatório Geral</title>
    <style>

        body {
            margin-top: -20px;
            margin-left: -20px;
            margin-right: -5px;
            padding:0
        }

        .borda3 {
            border:1px solid #999;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        #borda2 td {
            border: 1px solid #999;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: auto;

        }

        .centro {
            text-align: center;
        }

        .tabela {
            width: 100%;
        }

        span {
            font-size: 100px;
        }

        td {
            font-size: 11px;
        }

        html {
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        #customers {
            font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        #customers td, #customers th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;

        }

        #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

        #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

        #customers th {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 9px;
        }

        #customers td {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        #customers a {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .nome{
            width: 180px;
        }

        .matricula{
            width: 15px;
        }

        .numeros{
            width: 15px;
        }

        .logo{
            padding-left: 50px;

        }

        .logo a strong{
            font-size: 15px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .logo a{
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        .assinatura{
            font-size: 9px;
            margin-left: 60px;

        }
    </style>
</head>
{{--beginning of the loop--}}
<body>
    <table class="tabela borda3">
        <tr>
            <td width="40%" class="centro">
                <table class="logo">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <img style="margin-left:20px; margin-top: -20px;width:220px; height: 65px;" src="img/logo_sarh.jpg">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label for=""><a><strong> </strong></a></label><br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a>Referência:</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a>Período:</a></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td width="40%" class="centro">
                <table class="assinatura">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 30px; text-align: left"><label for="">Em: _____/ _____/___________</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-bottom: -20px; height: 50px; text-align: center">
                            <label for="">____________________________________________</label><br>
                         <label style="font-size: 10px" for=""> SUPERVISOR</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="height: 30px; text-align: left"><label for="">VISTO</label></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-bottom: -10px; height: 50px; text-align: center">
                            <label for="">____________________________________________</label><br>
                            <label style="font-size: 10px" for=""> SECRETÁRIO(A)</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>
    <table id="customers">
        <tr>
            <th class="nome">Nome</th>
            <th class="matricula">Matrícula</th>
            <th class="numeros">Dias</th>
            <th class="numeros">Faltas</th>
            <th class="numeros">Vac</th>
            <th class="numeros">LSV</th>
            <th class="numeros">L M</th>
            <th class="numeros">Aci. Trab</th>
            <th class="numeros">Adi. Not</th>
            <th class="numeros">H.E Normal D</th>
            <th class="numeros">H.E Normal N</th>
            <th class="numeros">H.E Dom/Fer. D</th>
            <th class="numeros">H.E Dom/Fer. N</th>
            <th class="numeros">Ins.</th>
        </tr>
        {{--beginning of the loop--}}
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>Augusto Damasceno Pedrozo</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>12345678</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>30</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>2</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20,02</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20,02</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20,02</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20,02</a></td>
            <td style="height: 20px;"><a>20</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="height: 20px;" colspan="14">Observação:</td>
        </tr>
        {{--end of the loop--}}
    </table>
</body>
{{--end of the loop--}}
</html>
```

Could anyone give me some direction to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried with while in the first loop and for in the second loop. I am not able to do the break in the while to change the page (In case of change of department)

Comment: I need to change the page when the sequence of employee departments changes. The way I do it, it ends the while and does not stop running all the employees.

Comment: you should paste the code you tried in the question, and explain what you expected it to do and what you got instead, it'll make it much easier for other people to help you out.

Comment: I'll do it and put it here. Thank you William

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
@foreach($customers as $customer)
    @while ($loop->index <= 15)                   
        <!-- build table row here -->     

    @endwhile                             
    <!-- page break -->                                          
@endforeach
```

- in laravel there is a loop variable
- this variable tracks the current index and some other things
- you can check if the current index is smaller or equal to 15, perform page break, grab next, check if department is same as before, repeat

for the department changes you can set a variable which holds the current department and compare it in the loop like:

```
@if($current_dep !== $cust->department)
    <!-- page break -->
@endif
```

#### don't forget to check for last record

```
@while(!$loop->last)

@endwhile
```

further information on the `$loop` variable: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#the-loop-variable